# Strong and $\sigma$-strong topology on $B(H)$?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the strong topology and $\sigma$-strong topology. By definition, strong topology is the topology induced by the family of seminorms $p_\xi$, $\xi \in H$ where $p_\xi(T)=||T\xi||$ and the $\sigma$- strong topology is the topology induced by the family of seminorms $p_{(\xi_n)}$, $(\xi_n)\subseteq H$ is such that $\sum_n||\xi_n||^2<\infty$ and $p_{(\xi_n)}(T)=(\sum_n||T\xi_n||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

It is clear that $\sigma$-strong topology is finer than strong topology. I want to prove that on the unit ball in $B(H)$, these two topologies are the same. 
In the proof it is written that the seminorms defining $\sigma$-strong topology is the uniform limit of strongly continuous seminorms. I am not understanding the terminologies here mentioned uniform limit and strong continuity and how does this imply the conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\bar\xi = (\xi_n)_n$ one of your sequences in in $\ell^2[H]$. By the convergence of the sum $\sum_n \| \xi_n \|_2^2$, we have that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can pick an $N$ such that
$
  \sum_{n > N} \| \xi_n \|_2^2 < \epsilon.
$
But that implies that the seminorm $p_{\bar\xi}(T)$ is bounded by
$$
  \begin{eqnarray}
    p_{\bar\xi}(T) & = & \Big( \sum_{n = 1}^N \| T \xi_n \|_2^2 + \sum_{n = N + 1}^\infty \| T \xi_n \|_2^2 \Big)^\frac12\\
     & \leq & N^\frac12 \max_{n \leq N} \{ \, p_{\xi_n}(T) \, \} + \Big( \sup_{n \geq N + 1} \| T_n \|\Big) \epsilon^\frac12.
  \end{eqnarray}
$$
From that it is easy to conclude, if $T_\beta \to T$ strongly and $T_\beta$, $T$ are in the unit ball, then for every $\epsilon$ you can take $N$ as above. Now use that the first term is a finite combinations of seminorms and therefore goes to $0$ to get that
$$
\lim_\beta p_{\bar\xi}(T_\beta - T) \leq  \Big( \sup_{\beta} \| T_\beta -T \|\Big) \epsilon^\frac12 \leq \sqrt{2} \epsilon^\frac12,
$$
but since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we can conclude.

Comment: What is $T_n$ here. I guess it is a typo. The second term will be less than or equal to $||T||\epsilon$? Also I saw somewhere that the seminorm defining the $\sigma$-weak topology is the uniform limit of strongly continuous seminorms and from this it will follow. What does the statement mean?